# Using an AHK script to extend to my second monitor

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors

When using a dual monitor setup every time I want to connect or disconnect the monitor I have to go into the display settings; is there a way that this can be bypassed with a AHK script? All the script needs to do is activate the monitor so it displays to the left hand side, it is the same monitor every time just I like to move my laptop around a lot and obviously cant move the second monitor.

Comment: When you ever move to Windows 7, you can use WIN+P to do this. ;-)

Comment: Windows 7 usually tries to put a monitor it recognizes back where it was before as soon as you plug it in - I'm surprised Vista doesn't.  (Or is this maybe a VGA connection?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic21800.html) AutoHotkey forum thread contains such a script.